# Mono: Too many heap sections Increase MAXHINCR or MAX_HEAP_SECTS when app takes more than 4 GB in memory

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I am running my mono application at a bitnami linux with 8 GB of memory. It is a sophisticated file merger application, which is supposed to take a lot of RAM as it works.
But every time it takes more than 4 GB of RAM, it crashes with following error message:

```
Too many heap sections: Increase MAXHINCR or MAX_HEAP_SECTS
Stacktrace:

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.__icall_wrapper_mono_array_new_specific (intptr,int) <0x0005e>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.__icall_wrapper_mono_array_new_specific (intptr,int) <0x0005e>
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, System.Nullable`1<int>>.InitArrays (int) <0x00040>
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, System.Nullable`1<int>>.Init (int,System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1<string>) <0x00091>
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, System.Nullable`1<int>>..ctor () <0x0001b>
  at lawyerGatherBot.Merger.LawyerRepresentation..ctor (string) <0x00080>
  at lawyerGatherBot.Merger.MergeLawyerRecords.Map (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<string>) <0x00167>
  at lawyerGatherBot.Program.Main (string[]) <0x00161>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00082>

Native stacktrace:

    mono() [0x48bd6b]
    /lib/libpthread.so.0(+0xf8f0) [0x7f6c4198a8f0]
    /lib/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x7f6c4162ba75]
    /lib/libc.so.6(abort+0x180) [0x7f6c4162f5c0]
    mono() [0x5da188]
    mono() [0x5d7ec0]
    mono() [0x5d8349]
    mono() [0x5d8534]
    mono() [0x5d86f1]
    mono() [0x5d3571]
    mono() [0x5d4752]
    mono() [0x5d50e5]
    mono(mono_array_new_specific+0xba) [0x53716a]
    [0x40df9f2f]

Debug info from gdb:


=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================

Aborted
```

Here's the output of mono -V :

```
Mono JIT compiler version 2.8.2 (tarball Tue Aug 30 18:06:04 UTC 2011)
Copyright (C) 2002-2010 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          debugger softdebug
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

What should I do to be able to run memory-intensive apps on mono?

*UPDATE
I screw up and compiled the app for 32 bit systems. Hence, this error.

Comment: Please accept answers on the questions you asked, that may help you getting an answer on this question.

Comment: Did you check you are running the 64bit version of Mono? The 32 bit version won't be able to access more than 4GB, as it can't address that additional memory...

Comment: Here's the output of mono -V:
Mono JIT compiler version 2.8.2 (tarball Tue Aug 30 18:06:04 UTC 2011)
Copyright (C) 2002-2010 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          debugger softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)

Comment: @Arsen, it seems your Mono runtime is not prepared to deal with your memory requirements. `MAXHINCR` and `MAX_HEAP_SECTS` look like preprocessor options you can specify when building a custom version of the runtime. Are you willing to go that route? Are you positive you *really* need that amount of RAM, of can something be done to alleviate this requirement?

Comment: @Frederic: If I can recompile mono to work properly with my app, I'll do that, just tell me how. 
And yes, I need that much memory because I've got plenty of data randomly distributed along different files. The other solution I considered was dumping all that data into temp files. But I'd rather would use RAM if I can

Comment: @Arsen, I would tell you how (see [there](http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_From_Tarball) for starters and pass `CFLAGS=-DMAXHINCR=xxx -DMAX_HEAP_SECTS=yyy` to `configure`), but I don't know if I really can recommend it, as it might conflict with the runtime the rest of your system is using. What's your distribution?

Comment: @Arsen, also, did you consider memory-mapping the files?

Comment: @Frederic: I am using EC2 ami-0dce9c48 from US West with mono compiled and installed on it. The system is named Bitnami. At login it identifies itself as x86_64 GNU/Linux Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS

I did ./configure CFLAGS=-DMAXHINCR=9999999999999999. It doesn't seem to know -DMAX_HEAP_SECTS param.

I'll post an update when it recompiles and installs

Comment: @Arsen, my apologies, I forgot to quote the flags. It should be `CFLAGS="-DMAXHINCR=xxx -DMAX_HEAP_SECTS=yyy"`. You're running Unbuntu, so [ubuntu.se] might be of further assistance. Good luck :)

Comment: @Frederic: no, no effect :( . During compilation, there were some messages, that mono overwrites those. It's a shame

Comment: @Arsen, `some messages` probably mean you crossed some safety threshold. Try to use less RAM then. Commit data to temporary files, as you said, or maybe memory-map your source files. Stream everything you can. Or, if possible, parallelize your algorithm among multiple processes so you can consume more memory at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that this error stems from the Boehm GC.

Try this first. Download and build from source using the script below. In the configure part of the script, make this change:

./configure --with-large-heap=yes

Do this in addition to whatever other config issues you want to set. This should set the LARGE_CONFIG flag.

If you wanted to set it manually (I don't know why), here are the steps:

1. Download the mono source and run the script here

http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2011/08/install-mono-2-10-3-on-ubuntu-using-bash-script/

1. Now go back and add the following code to the top of

build/mono-2.10.8/libgc/include/gc_config_macros.h

```
#ifndef LARGE_CONFIG
#define LARGE_CONFIG
#endif
```

1. Now go up to build/mono-2.10.8 and run

make 
sudo make install

Hopefully this will compile a new mono that solves your problem. The resulting mono will be in /opt

Some of the most affected code is in libgc/include/private/gc_priv.h, but the maintainers have nicely put conditionals all over for the LARGE_CONFIG flag, so it's probably best to work with that.

Comment: I have a similar application which allocates alot of small objects (~4 GB worth of them) and I'm experiencing same crashes with it.

LARGE_CONFIG just made them rarer, using sgen GC as well. Using memory-mapped files is not an option.

It seems like Mono can't do heap compaction well... where can I take this issue further?

Answer (score 2):

Use mono 2.10.2 or later (possibly with the new GC with the option --gc=sgen). Your mono version is very old.

Comment: You mean to say, that Mono JIT compiler version 2.8.2 is older than 2.10.2?